# How to execute a Go app through Python and debug both in VScode at the same time?

Tags: python, go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have built a CLI Go application and a Python script that executes the Go app through [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

I use VScode to build both projects. Is there a way to run and debug the Python script and also attach the Go debugger of VScode whenever the Go application executes? At the moment I can only debug either.

My `launch.json` contains a simple debug configuration for Python:

```
    {
      "name": "Python API",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "foo.py",
      "justMyCode": true,
    }
```

Whereas the configuration to debug the Go app only supports the `launch` request, and no option for an `attach` mode:

[image]

Comment: start the Go app from Python in the Go debugger and create an attach launch config to connect to the Go debugger, then start the attach config, you now have 2 debug sessions

Comment: That sounds promising but I have a follow-up on `create an attach launch config to connect to the Go debugger`. How would I do that? Did you mean to attach to the Python debugger instead?

Comment: read the VSC doc pages on debugging

Comment: you should be able to attach to the Go debugger, a `launch` requests starts the debugger withy a known socket number and then attaches the debugger interface to that socket, find the command line options of the go debugger or look at the command generated when you launch a go debug session

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#attach